# Button Type Border

Tags: image, button, border

I am trying to remove this white/grey border from the image but I can't, tried everything.

Original Image:

[image]

With the button type:

[image]

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="maquinas" value="" >
<img src="http://industriadeltenis.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/IMG-LOGO-620x330.jpg" >
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try below style to the button tag, hope it will work.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="maquinas" value="" style="padding:initial">
  <img src="imgpath" >
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: The border is reduced but I still have a white square and it's not the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [bootstrap overlay class](https://gist.github.com/petehouston/85dd33210c0764eeae55)

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="maquinas" value="">
  <img src="imgpath" style=" position: absolute;clip: rect(0px,60px,100px,0px);">
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am just adding your code without css and I got 5 % of my image.

Comment: you must adjust what size you want?